# cómo dar estilo a un contenedor div style

Tags: css

Os dejo aquí el ejemplo. Dentro de este contenedor hay otros tantos anidados, además de h1, etiquetas de texto p, imágenes, etc.

```
div style="margin-top: 50px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto"
```

El problema es que si escribo sólo `div{ estilos }` no es solución porque no es el único contenedor así.

Como este div tengo otros cientos. Todo forma parte de un proyecto con html5, php, javascript, una base de datos, css inline, etc. La pregunta es porque deseo sacar ese código css inline a un archivo css.
Gracias.

Comment: para que tu código aparezca formateado, has de seleccionarlo y presionar `ctrl + k`

Comment: Todo ese código es generado?, no puedes ponerle una clase al div?

Answer (score 2):

Si no quieres que esos estilos se apliquen a todos los elementos, simplemente a un `div` específico y que no se repita a los demás,quedando así

```
<div id="unico"></div>
```

Ahora en tu archivo .css aplicas los estilos así

```
div#unico{
    estilos aquí
}
```

Por el contrario si deseas aplicar estilos a un grupo de `div` entonces deberás usar una `class` común para todos los que compartirán estilos

```
<div class="class1">1</div>
<div class="class1">2</div>
```

Aplicando estilos por css quedaría así

```
div.class1{
    estilos squí
}
```

Lo anterior aplicará estilos solo a los `div` que contengan dicha clase que pueden ser 2 o más

**ACLARACIÓN**

- Los `id` son identificadores para elementos únicos
- Las `class` son para múltiples elementos

Comment: Consulta, he leido habitualmente que los `id` deberian utilizarse unicamente para interactuar con JavaScript, y que cualquier estilo particular que se quiera crear deberia ser una `class`, aun si solo se ocupara una vez; es esto una buena practica o realmente no tiene importancia?

Comment: tengo la misma referencia, pero JS tiene métodos tanto para trabajar con `id` como con `class` sin embargo su esencia de uso no se debe perder

Comment: Claro claro, podemos usar cualquiera con JavaScript, pero talvez sera por convencion o por manetener algun tipo de "estandar" que se prefiere uno en vez de otro

Answer (score 0):

Complementando la información adicional, aunque especifiques un estilo exclusivo para ese `<div>`, ten en cuenta que lo irán heredando los otros elementos anidados en su interior sin estilo definido previamente.